# Simple query for listing elements in mysql

Tags: mysql

**I have two tables**::

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MasterListItemtype;
+----------------------+------------------------+
| MasterListItemtypeID | MasterListItemtypeName |
+----------------------+------------------------+
|                    1 | Starters               |
|                    2 | Main Course            |
|                    3 | Side Course            |
|                    4 | Others                 |
|                    5 | Desert                 |
+----------------------+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM MasterListMenuItems;
+------------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------+
| MasterListMenuID | MasterListMenuName    | Vegan | MasterListItemtypeID |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------+
|                1 | Vada                  |     1 |                    1 |
|                4 | Chinese Chicken Salad |     0 |                    1 |
|                5 | Dosa Chicken Salad    |     0 |                    1 |
|                6 | Gobi Manchuri         |     1 |                    2 |
|                7 | Indian Salad          |     1 |                    3 |
|                8 | Gobi Chilli Manchuri  |     1 |                    2 |
|                9 | Chocolate IceCream    |     1 |                    5 |
|               10 | Vanilla IceCream      |     1 |                    5 |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**note here**::

- `MasterListMenuID` is primary key of `MasterListMenuItems`
- `MasterListItemtypeID` is primary key of `MasterListItemtype`
- `MasterListItemtypeID` is Foreign key of `MasterListMenuItems`

  .

---

**How to make a Mysql query so that**::

I need to list the elements in `MasterListMenuName` of table `MasterListMenuItems` which are `starters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select MasterListMenuName from  MasterListMenuItems where MasterListItemtypeID 
 = 
 (  
select MasterListItemtypeID from MasterListItemtype where MasterListItemtypeName 
= 'Starters')
```

(OR)

```
select m.MasterListMenuName from  MasterListMenuItems m 
join  MasterListItemtype n
on m.MasterListItemtypeID = n.MasterListItemtypeID 
and m.MasterListMenuName = 'Starters'
```

Comment: Just one more question.... I also saw one of answers of Akshat Singhal.... he used nested queries .... is using nested queries better or join ?

Comment: @NewBie, if you see my answer carefully, I have used the same. I have given you 2 options; one with subquery and another with joins. Basically, joins are better than subquery and you should avoid subquery if you can replace the same with a join.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM MasterListMenuItems WHERE MasterListMenuItems.MasterListItemtypeID IN (SELECT MasterListItemtype.MasterListItemtypeID FROM MasterListItemtype WHERE MasterListItemtype. MasterListItemtypeName = 'Starters');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select MasterListMenuName from MasterListMenuItems mi 
    inner join MasterListItemtype it 
        on mi.MasterListItemtypeID = it.MasterListItemtypeID 
where it.MasterListItemtypeName = 'Starters'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the foreign key for starter, in your case is 1.

```
SELECT * FROM MasterListMenuItems WHERE MasterListItemtypeID = 1
```